# React Native invalid directory /users/node_module/https

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

I am trying to use https npm package with react native, getting the following error:

> Invalid directory /users/node_module/https

Below is the code

```
var React = require('react-native');
var Https = require('https');
```

I have tried restarting the package manger, clearing the cache and even deleting the `node_modules` folder and again initialising the project, but nothing seems to work.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

have tried all the solution working on this link, but nothing is working for me

Comment: Is the directory there (on disk)?

Comment: Downgrading npm version doesn't work either

Comment: @rik yes directory is there actually this should not happen , react should look for the module in the project directory .

this is similar to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 but all the solution mentioned there are not working for me

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

I cannot install and use any additional npm packages as a module.

The module path is correct. I cut and paste the path displayed in xcode into a terminal to test path was valid and correct.

Using:

- OS X 10.11.3
- npm 3.3.12
- node v5.5.0
- react-native-cli: 0.1.10
- react-native: 0.21.0
- xcode 7.2.1

No work-arounds helped including:

- npm3
- rm -rf node_modules
- npm start from ./node_modules/react-native.
- watchman watch-del-all
- rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*
- npm cache clean && npm
- install Creating a new project from scratch
- Modifying **react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/index.js:98**

  -shouldThrowOnUnresolvedErrors: (, platform) => platform === 'ios',
  +shouldThrowOnUnresolvedErrors: (, platform) => { return false; },

How does anyone get any work done in react-native without using additional npm packages?